# Python compare tuples with different data types but same values

Tags: python, comparison, tuples

I am trying to compare two tuples to determine if there is any difference.
The code I use is not solving my problem because I do not care about if value has different types. In the example I do not care if value "1" is string or integer. I would like to be these tuples considered equal. How could I achieve that?

```
tup1 = (1,2,3)
tup2 = ('1',2,3) # the difference is value 1 is of string data type
pprint(tup1 == tup2) # returns false
pprint(list(set(tup1) - set(tup2))) # returns [1]
```

Comment: `tuple(map(int,tup2))==tup1`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: originally I was surprised because it looked like you were posting an answer as a comment, but then you posted a different answer as an answer, so now I'm just confused.

Comment: @DSM, I added more than one option. I was not sure if one tuple always had a specific type and the second was a mixture or both could have mixed types.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but those are *answers*, not comments.  Asking clarifying questions is what comment are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tup1 = (1,2,3)
tup2 = ('1',2,3)

print(map(str,tup2))== map(str,tup1)) # tuple(map.. python 3
```

Or if you know they are all ints in one and a mixture of string digits and ints in the other just cast one:

```
tuple(map(int, tup2)) == tup1
```

If you are using python 2 you can use `itertools.izip` and `itertools.imap`:

```
from itertools import imap, izip

print(all(x == y for x,y in izip(imap(str, tup2),imap(str, tup1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast everything to `str` and then compare:

```
pprint([str(x) for x in tup1] == [str(x) for x in tup2])
```

Or:

```
all(str(x) == str(y) for x, y in zip(tup1, tup2))
```

Or:

```
map(str, tup1) == map(str, tup2)
```

Comment: Or `map(str, tup1) == map(str, tup2)`.

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure about which is more appropriate, casting to `int` or `str`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not if OP is using Python 3.x

Comment: Well i think mapping to string would be good, as it will not restrict to tuple comparison of having numeric values only.

Comment: @TanveerAlam, on the other hand you want to fail ASAP if you expect only `int`s. So it's really use-case dependant.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Yeah that's True, I was thinking in a more generic way.

Comment: @thefourtheye true enough!

Answer (score 1):

if your concern is only between `int` and `str` (generally, any object that can be converted to `int`), you can convert every element into int before comparison:

`tuple(map(int,tup1)) == tuple(map(int,tup2))`